# No se puede anular la selección de una palabra en un área de texto cuando copio al portapapeles

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría poder seleccionar una palabra y anular la selección de una palabra en un área de texto. Puedo seleccionar una palabra en un área de texto usando el siguiente código. Sin embargo, la palabra permanece seleccionada después de ejecutar el método removeAllRanges() y removeRange(). ¿Hay algo que me falta para anular la selección de la palabra? Agradecería cualquier ayuda que pueda proporcionar.

```js
//Button Copy
function copyToClipBoard(elementCopy) {
  var inputHidden = document.createElement('textarea');
  inputHidden.value = document.getElementById(elementCopy).innerText;
  console.log(elementCopy.innerText);
  document.body.appendChild(inputHidden);
  inputHidden.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(inputHidden);
  document.getElementById('btnCopy_id').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>";
  
  setTimeout(() => {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE NO ME FUNCIONA BIEN
        document.getElementById('btnCopy_id').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clone'></i>";
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p id="textCopy">
Hola yo soy el codigo a copiar
</p>
<div class="btns-accessibility" id="btnCopy_id">
 <i onclick=copyToClipBoard("textCopy") class="fa fa-clone" href="#">     </i>
</div>
```

Cabe resaltar que este codigo aqui en Sctack Overflow no funciona.

Comment: Prueba moviendo`document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` fuera del setTimeout

Comment: No me funciono :(

Answer (score 0):

No veo cual es el problema, el código funciona bien, lo que no veo es donde está la palabra resaltada que luego se queda resaltada. Si utilizas un textarea oculto, tal y como haces usando el inputHidden, no puedes ver el texto seleccionado.
Sí que tienes un par de errores, los cuales te enumero para que los repares, por un lado cuando llamas a la función `copyToClipBoard` le estás pasando como parámetro un string con el nombre del elemento que contiene el texto, por tanto
`console.log(elementCopy.innerText);` siempre te mostrará "undefined" puesto que una cadena de texto no tiene "innerText". Por otro lado, cuando cambias el icono al botón, para que muestre un check, estás cambiando el HTML del contenedor (div) que contiene el botón, por tanto el botón deja de existir.
A parte de esos dos errores, he cambiado el nombre del inputHidden por inputHiddenx, de esta forma el texarea se muestra y puedes ver que sí que se muestra el texto resaltado y sí que se deselecciona al utilizar `removeAllRanges()`.
Puedes probarlo en el snippet que este sí funciona.

```js
//Button Copy
function copyToClipBoard(elementCopy) {
  var inputHiddenx = document.createElement('textarea');
  inputHiddenx.value = document.getElementById(elementCopy).innerText;
  console.log(elementCopy.innerText);
  document.body.appendChild(inputHiddenx);
  inputHiddenx.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.getElementById('btnCopy_id').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>"; 
  setTimeout(() => {
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE NO ME FUNCIONA BIEN
        document.getElementById('btnCopy_id').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clone'></i>";
    }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(inputHiddenx);
    }, 2000);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p id="textCopy">
Hola yo soy el codigo a copiar
</p>
<div class="btns-accessibility" id="btnCopy_id">
 <i onclick=copyToClipBoard("textCopy") class="fa fa-clone" href="#">     </i>
</div>
```